# Code::Blocks C/C++ windows.h missing fatal error

Tags: c++, c, windows

problem:

I tried to compile a simple c++ source file with Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Compiler,
and I encountered an error.
I've installed Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 and MinGW and located the windows.h file,
I've also configured the directory of extra files in Code::Blocks.

code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main(){
    printf("Hello World!");

    getchar();
}
```

error:

```
F:\test2.cpp(3) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'windows.h': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Show us the complete code.

Comment: Just get rid of `#include <windows.h>` - you don't need it. You don't need `#include <stdlib.h>` either.

Comment: I actually just made this testing program to show the problem, I have another project working on which have the same problem. and so I need windows.h to work.

Comment: Take a look: http://apolyton.net/showthread.php/152877-include

Comment: @AlterMann I've already installed the Windows 7 SKD before I posted, but I still have the problem...

Comment: @AlterMann - not really relevant or useful. When one downloads MinGW, italready comes with the required `.h` and `.a` files. The platform SDK comes with `.h` and `.lib` files - suitable for developing with Visual Studio, _not_ for use with MinGW.

Comment: @enhzflep The problem I'm having isn't that I don't have the required header files to compile, the problem is that I can't get them to work even I've already configured the directory and stuff. I'm really frustrated because I changed from Dev-C++ to C::B and thought it would be a better IDE.

Comment: @maxloo2 - if you install `codeblocks-13.12mingw-setup.exe` from this page: http://www.codeblocks.org/downloads/26 then you should be good to go. I've had trouble in the past with `codeblocks-13.12mingw-setup-TDM-GCC-481.exe`, but never with the former. **EDIT:** CB _is_ much better. :)

Comment: @enhzflep I uninstalled my original CB installment and reinstalled    `codeblocks-13.12mingw-setup.exe`, but the problem is still there, somehow.

Comment: Hmmmm. - On my machine, the install directory is: `C:\Program Files(x86)\CodeBlocks`. If I then open C::B and goto Settings->Compiler, the `Selected Compiler` is "GNU GCC Compiler". If I then open the `Toolchain executables` tab, `Compiler's installation directory` is "C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW" - both of these were default - I just had to select `GNU GCC` as the default compiler during the installation process. Are your settings the same - or more specifically, does the `Compiler's installation directory` entry point to the location of MinGW? (EDIT: I'm on Win7)

Comment: @enhzflep I can compile with GNU, but I can't  while using Microsoft Visual C++ 2003 compiler.

Comment: Ahhhh! Okay then, if I do the same process, and set the compiler drop-down to "Microsoft Visual Studio C++ 2010", the locations are all different. Also, some extra settings are entered (by the installer or CB). `Compiler's install directory` is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC", while the `Compiler` tab of the "Search Directories" tab also contains two entries: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include` and `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include` - I don't recall the location of V2s003, nor do I have it installed at present.

Comment: I also note that there are entries in the `Linker` and `Resource Compiler` tab of the `Search Directories` tab. In these cases, the location is the same, except the `include` at the end has been changed to `lib` for the `Linker` and is actually still `include` for the `Resource Compiler` tab. Does your install match this structure? (with appropriate changes made for the location of your VS2003 install) - Also, C::B can auto-detect the location of compilers, though I don't recall how to do that just now. Incidentally, I use VS IDE if I want VS compiler - the debugger is **MUCH** better than GDB

Comment: @enhzflep Thanks! I added the dir of the "SKDs" at Search Directories tab and it is finally working! Not sure what's the reason because I'm just a newbie but well, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to utilize multiple compilers when using the Code::Blocks IDE, you need to ensure that the settings for each compiler are properly configured. These may be accessed via the `Settings->Compiler` menu option.

After selecting the compiler that one wishes to configure, you need to select the `Search Directories` tab and ensure that the `Compiler`, `Linker` and `Resource Compiler` tabs contain appropriate folders.
Each tab will possibly need several folders entered into the search box.

Using the example of the `Visual Studio C++ 2010` compiler, each tab will contain a reference to both

1. the appropriate folder, as found in the install location of *VS*
2. the appropriate folder, as found in the install location of the
   *Platform SDK*

In my case, the folder locations are:

**Compiler**

- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include

**Linker**

- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\lib
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\lib

**Resource Compiler**

- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include