# Implicit declaration of function 'SetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx'

Tags: c, windows, winapi, console, console-application

I'm new to C and making a console application where I need to change the default 16-color palette of the Windows console. I found out through [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48071097/windows-c-change-console-color-values) that I need to use the [`SetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolescreenbufferinfoex) function, however, my compiler insists that no such function is declared (I've only included `windows.h`).

Also, it doesn't recongnise the `CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFOEX` structure that is needed for the function to work and only recognises `CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO`.

I've been searching for a solution for this for days and the closest thing I found was an answer [here](https://cboard.cprogramming.com/cplusplus-programming/139494-getconsolescreenbufferinfoex-function.html) saying that I need to specify in my code that I'm targeting versions of Windows that are Vista or later. So I've tried defining
`#define NTDDI_VERSION NTDDI_VISTA` and `#define _WIN32_WINNT _WIN32_WINNT_VISTA`, but that didn't work either.

Remember that I'm new to C, so please try to make any answers and explanations as simple as possible (I'm using Code::Blocks and Windows 10).

> **EDIT:** I did a lot of searching around and here's what I found to help save some time for anyone that might have the same problem (**a lot of the information below could be wrong** so be warned and feel free to correct it if that's indeed the case):
>
> - `SetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx` is a function that's only included in the `ConsoleApi2.h` header (used by `windows.h`) from the [Windows SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk) and as such, needs the SDK in order to work.
> - The MinGW compiler [doesn't work well (if at all) with the SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20389408/mingw-g-winapi-winsdk-lost-in-confusion). It uses its own implementation of `windows.h` with only partial support for the SDK functions.
> - [It is possible to use the VC++ compiler with Code::Blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43242185/how-can-i-use-codeblocks-with-the-most-recent-versions-of-the-vc-compiler/43242195#43242195), in order to access the SDK functions. (however, I couldn't get it to work, so I just installed Visual Studio intead).

Comment: See the answer to this question for how to include windows.h correctly. The answer might be slightly out of date so you have to look for the correct menu.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26338747/codeblocks-c-c-windows-h-missing-fatal-error